# Polars - Glob read Parquet from S3 only read first file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-polars

I try to read some Parquet files from S3 using Polars.

Those files are generated by Redshift using UNLOAD with PARALLEL ON.

The 4 files are : `0000_part_00.parquet`, `0001_part_00.parquet`, `0002_part_00.parquet`, `0003_part_00.parquet`

When I use : `pl.read_parquet("s3://my_bucket/my_folder/*.parquet")`, it returns the result for only the first file (`0000_part_00.parquet`) -> 340 rows.

Weird thing is that running the same command locally : `pl.read_parquet("*.parquet")`,  will return all the rows -> 1239 rows.

Is it normal behavior or I am missing something here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it normal behavior or I am missing something here ?

That's normal *and* you're missing something.

From the docs:

> ### Parameters
>
> source
> Path to a file, or a file-like object. If the path is a directory, that
> directory will be used as partition aware scan.
> If `fsspec` is installed, it will be used to open remote files.

In the case of your local system, it identifies that as a directory and uses a partition aware scan. For accessing s3, it uses fsspec and doesn't really recognize the `*` in the path.

Instead do:

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import fsspec #or whatever the s3 wrapper is called
s3fs=fsspec.filesystem('s3', connection_string="xxxx")
myds=ds.dataset("s3://my_bucket/my_folder/", filesystem=s3fs)
df = pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(myds).collect()
```

Answer (score 3):

The current `0.20.7` version of `polars` simply works

- eagerly with `pl.read_parquet(source)` or
- lazily with `pl.scan_parquet(source)`

Where `source = "s3://bucket/*.parquet"` [source](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/io/cloud-storage/#reading-from-cloud-storage)

---

If the AWS credentials are not available as environment variable, it is possible to pass a `storage_options` argument like:

```
storage_options = {
    "aws_access_key_id": "<secret>",
    "aws_secret_access_key": "<secret>",
    "aws_region": "us-east-1",
}
df = pl.scan_parquet(source, storage_options=storage_options)
```